# Java, Android - how to convert a string to a number?

Tags: java, android, string

I'm developing an application where user will interact using Voice. Whenever the user says first, second, third etc.. i need to convert string "first" to int  1, string "second" to int 2.

So far what i have found out is that([Java-Android How to convert letters in a string to specified number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29425880/java-android-how-to-convert-letters-in-a-string-to-specified-number)), converting each letter in a string to respective number and then return some number. But i this is not what i need. I'm really stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no built in API for this.  You're going to have to write it completely yourself.  How high a number are you going to need?  If its relatively small, a simple map will do it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i know there is no built in api.  I don't how long number might grow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062022/how-to-convert-words-to-a-number

Answer (score 4):

**There is no exact way to do so . But for getting the functionality get done u can use Switch case
For example:-**

```
switch(WordNumber) {
   case First:
       System.out.println(1);
       return 1;
      break; // optional

   case Two:
       System.out.println(2);
       return 2;
      break; // optional

   // You can have any number of case statements.
   default : // Optional
      // Statements
}
```

Comment: Good solution, since OP commented after your answer that there is not specific limit, I would say the answer is still valid !

Answer (score 2):

You will need to split the value receive, to analyse each step. Since you don't have limited value, you will need to create a map for every numbers ... this is a too much.

So just create something like :

```
{ "one", "two", "three", ... "nine" }
{ "ten, "twenty", "thirteen", ... "nineteen"}
.. hundreds
.. thousands
.. specific case for eleven, twelves, ...
```

Then you wil need to analyse the value like `"twenty two"` by spliting it and search for each corresponding.

```
twenty = index 1 of tens array => (1 + 1) * 10 = 20
two = 2 => index 1 in unit array => 1 + 1 = 2

20 + 2

22
```

Off course, this need to be think a bit more, but this will give you a good system to read every number possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you define a list with all those string cardinals, then you can use **indexOf** and get the value you are looking for but carefully consider the null element: 
either add a null-cardinal element to the list or add 1 to the index value

```
List<String> cardinal = Arrays.asList("first", "second", "third", .. etc);
System.out.println(cardinal.indexOf("first") + 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will make use of the logic.

Comment: THis is a bad way of doing it.  indexOf is O(n).  Horrible performance.

Comment: @GabeSechan then what would you suggest?

Comment: Map<String, Integer>.  Same idea, but an O(1) lookup time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you have at least some way of getting the string values?

If the numbers are relatively small (~10), then a hashmap can do it. Just save them manually beforehand and look them up by the String.

```
HashMap<String, Integer>
```

If you got a much larger list (~100), you are going to have a method that would divide the incoming int, into sub numbers. So in this case, you would look at ten value and combine it with the post value.

```
2 = Second

22 - Twenty-second 

52 - Fifty-second
```